# Can anyone give me an illustration of a graph that satisfies the following theorem concerning connected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

**A connected graph has an Eulerian walk if and only if the number of odd vertices in it is either 0 or 2.**

Note: Eulerian path and Eulerian walk is the same. My prof uses Eulerian walk that's why that is what I have written.

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://mydevelopedworld.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/housegraph1.png

Comment: @Ben Hi! Thank you for the illustration! But, can you explain how come that illustration satisfies the said theorem? Since to be a connected graph, you need to have even degree on each vertex and vertex 1 has already 3 degrees which is odd. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: To be connected you just need to have a path between every pair of vertices. So there are lots of connected graphs with odd degree vertices. For example $K_2$

Comment: **Every graph** satisfies this theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, all connected graphs satisfy the theorem as they either:
 a) have 2 or 0 odd degree vertices and an Eulerian path, or 
 b) have 1 or 3+ odd-degree vertices and don't have a Eulerian path.

The housegraph example given has exactly one vertex of odd degree so it doesn't have a Eulerian path.

Strangely, the definition given [on Wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianPath.html) :

> A connected graph has an Eulerian path iff it has at most two graph
>   vertices of odd degree.

is wrong, as it would include graphs with a single vertex of odd degree.

Comment: I think that Wolfram Mathworld is on safe ground here: there is no graph with exactly one vertex of odd degree.